# How to access containing structure from a member in C?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, linux-kernel

I'm working with a few kernel modules (4.19.97) and I allocate `struct my_sock` like the following.

```
struct my_target {
    union thingA { ... } a;
    struct thingB *b;
};

struct my_sock {
    struct sock sk;
    // ...
    struct my_target target;
};

struct my_sock *my_s;

my_s = my_sock_alloc();
// ...
my_s->sk.sk_prot->init(sk);
```

The above ends up calling this callback.

```
static int my_init(struct sock *sk)
{   
    // I do the following because I cannot pass in the allocated 
    // `struct my_sock` into this function.
    struct my_sock *ms = my_sk(sk);

    // I want to access my_s->my_target or any field within 
    // `struct my_target` here, but at this point, `ms` is 
    // pointing to the the first member of `struct my_sock`, and 
    // not the originally allocated `my_s`.
    ms->target.a;
}

static inline struct my_sock* my_sk(const struct sock *s)
{
    return container_of(s, struct my_sock, sk);
}

// Here's how my_s gets allocated. Note that this is not the same
// structure as the first member of `struct my_sock`.
struct my_sock* my_sock_alloc(void)
{
    struct my_sock *sk = NULL;

    sk = kmem_cache_zalloc(my_sk_cachep, GFP_KERNEL);

    if (!sk)
        return NULL;

    return sk;
}
```

And here's the problem. The kernel has the code for `container_of` within `include/linux/kernel.h` which `casts a member of a structure out to the containing structure`, per the commentary.

When I use `my_sk(sk)`, I get the pointer address of the first member of the containing struct. The problem is that this is a different address than `my_s` which I allocated in the very first line and I need the pointer to `my_s` in order to access the `target` member.

Thoughts as to how I might access `my_s->target` within the call `my_init()` (and not make things global)?

Comment: What is `my_a`, should that be `my_s`? Where do you declare and assign `sk`?

Comment: There's so much missing and mistyped, this quesiton is impossible to answer.

Comment: @Barmar - my_target or anything within it. I'll try to clarify that in the OP. `sk` gets passed down to me, it's a `struct sock *`.

Comment: This is what I was referring to: Should `struct the_target target;` be `struct my_target target;`?

Comment: what is my_sk() ?

Comment: @ivan.ukr That's the last function he defined.

Comment: what is "sk" passed to init() in this line? "my_a->sk.sk_prot->init(sk);"

Comment: @ivan.ukr - sk represents the passed in socket from the BSD interface.

Comment: You still haven't shown how you set `sk`. That's most likely the problem.

Comment: Where do you call `my_init()`?

Comment: how sk is defined?

Comment: Maybe it should be `my_s->sk.sk_prot->init(my_s->sk);`?

Comment: my_s->sk.sk_prot->init(&my_s->sk);

Comment: @Barmar - no, the init(sk) is correct. `sk` gets passed in and I'd like to use that to access the containing struct.

Comment: Then the problem must be with how you're setting `sk`, it's not pointing to the `sk` member of `my_s`.

Comment: `container_of(s, struct my_sock, sk)` only works when you're passing an `sk` pointer that points to the `sk` member of a `my_sock` structure.

Comment: You're right. I'm not setting `sk` to the first member of `struct my_sock`.

Comment: Which is a different problem. So I'm going to mark Chris's answer as correct as pertaining to the question of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since `sk` is the very first field in `struct my_sock`, you can just cast the pointer and things should work:

```
struct my_sock *ms = (struct my_sock *)sk;
```

the extra work done in container_of is only needed when the "base" struct is *not* the first field.

Comment: But it should still work, since `offsetof()` will be `0`.

Comment: Risky. If the struct is edited this approach could break.

Comment: Agree with @nicomp, one should always use `container_of()`.